# ROS2 NAV2 global costmap is updating only previosly unseen area

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, nav2, global-costmap

I am using Ubuntu 22.04, ROS2 - Humble version.Installed all packages using package manager.

I am building simulation for my robot and I noticed very strange behavior for global costmap. My robot has 180 degrees lidar in front of it. And the problem is, that after starting Nav2 system in simulation, global costmap updates only area, which is unseen previously.

For-example, if robot has obstacle in front of it, it will not be included in global costmap at the beginning. I must turn robot away from obstacle and then back, only then it will be updates by global costmap. Here is my config file for global planner:

```yaml
vikings_bot_1/global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      map_topic: /map
      #transform_tolerance: 0.5
      robot_base_frame: vikings_bot_1/base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      #robot_radius: 0.175
      footprint: "[[0.8, 0.45], [-0.3, 0.45], [-0.3, -0.45], [0.8, -0.45]]"
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /vikings_bot_1/lidar_scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 5.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 4.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 4.0
        inflation_radius: 0.65
      always_send_full_costmap: True
```

Note: local costmap is updated correctly.

Here is video for the problem, as it might be hard to understand from description.

[image]

Any idea, where can be problem? I tried different planners as well, check parameters in config file..., but I could not find the cause of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very strange. Try turning off the static layer - are **any** laser scans working initially? Its not clear from your example that they are given that the other laser scans align with the map so that's already being inflated from the static layer. Any errors in the terminals? Perhaps the laser scans aren't actually making it into the costmap layers initially

Comment: I turned off static layer and **updated *giff** in original question. Yes, there is no update for global costmap initially although laser scan topic is working. Driving the robot  clears costmap under the footprint as expected. But the problem still exist, that global costmap is updated only when turning the robot.

There is no error in terminal launching path planner system.

Comment: I found the reason behind this. The problem was, that **lidar_link** in **map** frame was in negative z direction. So, by increasing lidar hight (z offset) problem disappeared.

Comment: Ah ok, I was about to say, that is so very strange, I have to think it was user error :-)

Comment: Can you click this answer as correct since its been debugged with the solution?